# Feet slip off flat/cleat hybrid pedals when it's wet

Tags: pedals, weather

I have those hybrid pedals that allow for both clipping in with cleats, and riding on flat pedals with ordinary shoes.

As I use my bike for cycling around the city, I mostly use the flats.

What I'm I'm finding though, is that when it's wet my shoes will slip of the pedals. I think it's because the clip in parts are slightly raised above the flat area.

Any suggestions for mitigating this?

Comment: Please post some photos of them.  I have a few ideas.  Gluing a traction strip of some sort to them.  Wrapping the loops that make them flat with a inner tube and some black electric tape for another.

Comment: You might look into your choice of shoes as well - obviously smart hard-soled shoes won't be very good but I generally ride in walking shoes/trainers on cheap platform pedals, and while all slide around a bit (even in the dry) some are much worse than others.  However if you *mainly* use the flats it might be worth getting good platform pedals and swapping to clipless for a long ride.

Comment: “I think it's because the clip in parts are slightly raised above the flat area.”

What pedals are those? The hybrid pedals I know have a completly flat side and one with clip in. Like the Shimano PD-M324: http://gearforcycletouring.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/shimano-m324-spd-pedals.jpg

Answer (score 2):

As you have observed, to get good traction for flats (especially in the wet) the pedals have to be grippy. To be able to rotate to enable the release of clipless shoes, the flats have to be slippery. Making the pedals grippy will mean unreliable release when using clipless.

Whatever you do, do not try to fix it with DIY solutions such as grip tape, screwing plates onto the pedals or into the leading edges (sticking up)  - You will improve the problem you have, but likely create a worse one - you might well find yourself under a B-Train or off the side of a trail and down a bluff when you cannot release in a hurry.

Solutions are to accept the compromise solution, try the combination flats one side, clips the other which solves this problem (but generates others such as the pedal is never the right way up.), or commit to either flats or clipless.

Personally I think the commitment to one or the other is the best solution.

[This question (and many others)](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30450/still-confused-about-clipless-walkable-shoes-and-dual-purpose-pedals) is worth reading if you want to consider other options.

Comment: There are "casual" shoes and sandals which take SPD as well as the new Shimano system, which you can walk around in all day, so you can go just clipless.

Comment: @Batman - that is what I do, do not want to get into answering the 'what type of pedal/shoe is best' question as the number of times it has been answered on this site is already once more than needed :)

Comment: The question is the answer! Bicycles work most efficiently when the shoe is attached to the pedal, be it by clip or strap and hook.