# Foot pain with cleated shoes

Tags: shoes, pain

I have cleated shoes. My feet do a lot of work floor miles and get I pain in ball of my foot. I feel like the cleat is pushing on the ball of my foot.

I was considering changing the shoe liner; would this help or not? I have N.W foot wear, they are at least 6 month old.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Martin. Klaster_1 and I have edited your post to try to make it clearer to other readers. If we have changed your intended meaning, please revert our edits.

Comment: If you are actually feeling the cleat inside your shoe then one suspects that it lacks a proper stiffener to spread the force out over a larger area.  Or the cleat position may not be properly set.  (And it would help to know what sort of cleat and pedal you're using.)

Comment: I once had a screw from the cleat poking through the insole! The I noticed the fact that the cleats were supplied with two different lengths of screws for different types of soles!

Answer (score 2):

Usually shoes for walking/running and cycling shoes are constructed quite differently: shoes you walk on are usually far less rigid, most have a much softer sole to absorb shocks/bumps, and of course do not have cleats.

As this is ergonomics and people are quite different, there is probably no general answer: I find walking in SPD Trecking shoes uncomfortable, but not enough that I would not use them every day.

For your specific problem, I guess changing liners could help. However you'd need very stiff liners that actually distribute unevenness. I have not yet seen those.

Assuming you have static workplace: maybe you could arrange having a second pair of shoes specifically for walking there?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear to me about "work floor miles", but you shouldn't be doing any general walking around in bike shoes for any significant distances.

Keep some regular shoes at work for this purpose.

If you are talking about during bike use, then I would consider getting a bike shoe with a more rigid base. Ones with carbon soles (if you can afford them) solved a problem I was having with tenderness at the ball of my foot.  Having the right bike shoes can be well worth the investment of about $150.

Also, I have gravitated toward mountain bike shoes with SPD pedals on all my bikes to simplify the situation and to make it easier for walking around.

Answer (score 0):

My Specialized Cadets are OK for a full day of walking and sitting, though I don't make a habit of it, instead I keep shoes under my desk.  I'm also used to wearing hiking boots with stiff soles so that makes them feel less unfamiliar.  The discussion under [my related question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/30450/7309) may also be of interest.

You should probably link to the exact shoes you've got -- at the moment it's not even clear what type of cleats you mean. If they're generously sized (which they shouldn't be) you may have room for a layer of something thin-but-stiff under the original liner or some sort of insole.