# Does the extra cage on SPD pedals help riding with normal shoes?

Tags: pedals, pedals-clipless

Some [Shimano Pedal Dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimano_Pedaling_Dynamics) (SPD) pedals come in two variants - without and with a cage - e.g. M520 and M530.

While it isn't the main purpose of the cage on M530 does it make cycling in normal shoes, esp with soft soles more comfortable?

UPDATE: 
99% of kilometers I do on this bike is with cycling shoes on and that's why I don't want platform/spd shoes (I have these actually). Once in a while I use it with normal shoes or even flip flops.

Comment: If you plan on riding often with normal shoes, you should look into something like the [Shimano A530 pedals](http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/road/pedals/pedals/pd-a530.html)  They have flats on one side and clips on the other. I've had a set for quite a while and they are a pretty good compromise. They are weighted so the clip in side is usually facing up, which makes it easy to clip in.

Comment: I prefer the 'more grippier' M324. (http://www.shimano-lifestylegear.com/us/pd/products/tour/002pd_m324.php), but they require shoes of some sort... they really bite even when your shoe is coated with oil, so there's no slipping.

Comment: @Kibbee - 99% of the kilometers I'll do on this bike will be done with cycling shoes on, but from time to time I may take the bike for a spin with no shoes on.

Answer (score 1):

I usually ride on [M424s](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/shimano-m424-clipless-spd-mtb-pedals/rp-prod7808), which are similar but with more grip on the cage.  I'd recommend those or the alloy-cage equivalent if you're thinking along these lines.  They're definitely OK with normal shoes.

I didn't want SPD one-side/platform the other: as an SPD novice I was going to be fiddling about enough without getting the pedal the right way up, but I also wanted to be able to jump on the bike in trainers/sandals for short distances -- maybe slower, maybe not very comfortable, but without my feet sliding off.  These pedals do all that.  They're fine in reasonably thick-soled normal shoes though you can feel the cleat.

I wanted to be able to [walk in my riding shoes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30450/still-confused-about-clipless-walkable-shoes-and-dual-purpose-pedals) which restricted my choice of shoes, and meant I had to file off a grippy bit of the pedal (I now also ride platforms in my SPD shoes as part of a bike-train-bike commute).

Also I avoid clipping in when I'm carrying my daughter in a toddler seat (or I  unclip well in advance of *anything* that might make me put my foot down).  By being able to pedal unclipped even in SPD shoes (axle under the arch of my foot, so not exactly efficient) I can drop her off then carry on riding.

It was a real bonus having them recently.  I did a long ride (for me: 48 miles/4 hours including stops) and being able to unclip and still pedal lightly helped when cramp was threatening.

*But* for family holidays, when I don't even take the SPD shoes, and have my daughter on the back more often than not, I swap to platform pedals.

Comment: After your update I still suggest a a cage (but a grippier one) would help you. I don't like riding in flipflops whatever pedals I have but I have tried it and the M424s have just enough grip if you press down evenly.

Answer (score 0):

For occasional use, there is also the option of "platform adapters": a (usually plastic) platform with an SPD cleat that clips onto your SPD pedals.
I have Time Z pedals on my AM bike and while they are possible to ride without clipping in, I wouldn't consider it an option for a ride of any length.
Another option is getting a cheap set of platform pedals and swapping.  I second the opinion that one-sided SPDs is a poor compromise.

Comment: I have M520 + shimano platform adaptors and they are fine. Platforms are not big enough but they do the job. I keep then in there just in case.