# Looking for an SPD cleat shoe similar to prior Specialized Sport RBX

Tags: shoes

I have a pair of older Specialized Sport RBX shoes with SPD cleats that I love.  I go back and forth between clipless with SPD cleats and toe cages.  The Specialized Sport RBX shoes have a ridgeless bottom with a recess for the SPD cleat.  As a result they are very comfortable walking off the bike, work very well when riding clipless with SPD cleats and slide smoothly in and out of toe cages.  I haven't been able to find any current shoes that have a similar bottom configuration.  Does anyone know of a shoe that is commparable.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at MTB shoes?

Comment: Or touring shoes, add they're often smoother underneath than mtb shoes. But I can find the sport RBX on clearance online so you might still be able to pick up a pair (I used to use specialized cadet, and found a pair online months after everywhere else had sold out - in a box that looked like it had been kicking around in a warehouse for some time, so it really is worth looking)

Comment: This question might help - https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/15377/walkable-clipless-pedal-shoe-to-replace-normal-shoe

Answer (score 1):

Bicycles SE is not really about product recommendations, so I won't give product links or dedicated recommendations.

If it is about the studs/ridges and getting into toe cages, you might also want to look for a SPD-compatible *road cycling* shoe. Unlike light gravel or MTB shoes, these often have pretty smooth soles and are more entry-level shoes, hence not as stiff as "pro shoes" that typically come with SPD-SL or equivalent pedal system compatibility, just not made for walking around except getting from your door to your bike and back.

It is probably best to go a online sports equipment store's page and look up by *"road cycling"* and *"SPD"* system until you find something you like. Here's an [Amazon link](https://www.amazon.com/spd-shoes/s?k=spd%20shoes) as a starting point.

If you are looking for a more casual shoe to walk in, there are e-bike/trekking specific shoes which are basically trekking shoes or sneakers with SPD support, a famous example is the Adidas Velosamba released last year but there plenty of options.

However, the Specialized shoe you are looking for is more in the road cycling segment, I suppose. You just need to find one where the cleat is in the sole, that might not be the case on every model but is often considered for convenience.

After some further googling, Specialized is still making [these](https://www.specialized.com/ee/en/sport-rbx-road-shoes/p/155435?color=229509-155435) if you couldn't find any alternatives.